# ClassNotFoundException CXFServlet migration JBoss 7 to Wildfly 13

Tags: jakarta-ee, cxf, jboss-eap-7, wildfly-13

really need some help. I'm on Jboss 7 migration to wildfly 13 with web application and facing this issue. I passed more week trying to solve it but didn't.

```
Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Oper
ation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"pvcp-payment-service-web.war\".POST_MODULE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of deployment \"pvcp-payment-service-web.war\"
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet from [Module \"deployment.pvcp-payment-service-web.war\" from Service Module Loader]
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet from [Module \"deployment.pvcp-payment-service-web.war\" from Service Module Loader]"}}}}
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

When I build application I didn't add apache cxf dependencies into a war cause in my pom I said it'll be provided. Why I did this because, first when tried to deploy application to the wdf server I got this error :

```
Failed to execute goal deploy: {"WFLYCTL0062: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Oper
ation step-1" => {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"pvcp-payment-service-web.war\".PARSE" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment \"pvcp-payment-service-web.war\"
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYWS0059: Apache CXF library (cxf-core-3.2.4.jar) detected in ws endpoint deployment; either provide a proper deployment replacing embedded libraries with container modul
e dependencies or disable the webservices subsystem for the current deployment adding a proper jboss-deployment-structure.xml descriptor to it. The former approach is recommended, as the latter approach causes most of the webservices Java EE and any JBossWS spe
cific functionality to be disabled."}}}}
```

Aftet go this error I added Jboss-deployement-structure.xml into which I ask to exclude apache cxf dependencies like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment> 
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.apache.cxf" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>  
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

But still taking same like last above.
So now dont know what I can do to fix this issue. Can anyone help me please. I'm so tired.
I really appreciate.
Thanks.

The web app pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pvcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>pvcp-payment-service</artifactId>
        <version>${parent-version}</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>pvcp-payment-service-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>pvcp-payment-service-web</name>
    <description>pvcp-payment-service-web</description>


    <scm>
        <connection>scm:....../trunk/${pom.artifactId}</connection>
    </scm>

    <properties>
        <cxf.version>2.4.6</cxf.version>
        <!-- <cxf.version>2.2.10</cxf.version> -->
        <spring-security-version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring-security-version>
        <jersey.version>1.19.1</jersey.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- PAYMENT-SERVICE-SERVICES DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pvcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>pvcp-payment-service-services</artifactId>
            <version>${parent-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- PV-COMMON-CRON DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pv</groupId>
            <artifactId>pv-common-cron</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-parent</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- COMMON-XFT-WS DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pv</groupId>
            <artifactId>pv-common-xft-ws</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.pv</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pv-io-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        

        <!-- CXF DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>saaj-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.soap</groupId>
                    <artifactId>saaj-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <!-- <scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
           <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING-SECURITY DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
                
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
            <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JERSEY DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>            
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.auth</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hmac-auth-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.16</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ASPECTJ DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.4</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- XERCES DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xerces</groupId>
            <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SERVLET-API DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- QUARTZ DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TAPESTRY DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>stax</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stax-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-ioc</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javassist</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>jboss</groupId>
                    <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.got5</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry5-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapestry-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${tapestry-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.apache.tapestry</groupId> 
            <artifactId>tapestry-upload</artifactId> 
            <version>${tapestry-version}</version> 
        </dependency>

        <!-- H2 DEPENDENCY -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.131</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- TEST DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <!--<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>junit</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>-->
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-vfs</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.GA</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.howardlewisship</groupId>
            <artifactId>tapx-datefield</artifactId>
            <!-- Version based on tapx-datefield-1.2-20120528.222450-13.pom -->
            <!-- Stored in local Nexus repository -->
            <version>1.2CP</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Support tools -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.bull.javamelody</groupId>
            <artifactId>javamelody-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.49.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.admin4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>admin4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
            <artifactId>jolokia-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Needed in Junit tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-modules-jakarta-commons</artifactId>
            <version>0.8a</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pvcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>pvcp-payment-service-services</artifactId>
            <version>${parent-version}</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Build Settings -->
    <build>
        <finalName>pvcp-payment-service-web</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>svn-revision-number-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13</version>
                <dependencies>
                   <dependency>
                       <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                       <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                       <version>1.8.3-1</version>
                   </dependency>
               </dependencies>      
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>revision</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>           
            </plugin>   
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <tasks>
                                <echo>Write the current version of the application.</echo>
                                <propertyfile
                                    comment="Build information for ${pom.artifactId}-${pom.version}"
                                    file="src/main/webapp/public/version.txt">
                                    <entry key="build.date" type="date" pattern="EEEE MMM dd, yyyy"
                                        value="now" />
                                    <entry key="build.time" type="date" pattern="HH:mm:ss"
                                        value="now" />
                                    <entry key="build.timestamp" type="date" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
                                        value="now" />
                                    <entry key="build.user.name" value="${user.name}" />
                                    <entry key="build.computer" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}" />
                                    <entry key="pom.artifactId" value="${pom.artifactId}" />
                                    <entry key="pom.version" value="${pom.version}" />
                                    <entry key="svn.revision" value="${pvcp-payment-service-web.revision}" />
                                    <entry key="svn.status" value="${pvcp-payment-service-web.status}" />
                                </propertyfile>
                            </tasks>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>ant</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
                        <type>jar</type>
                        <version>1.5.3-1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <serverName>${server.name}</serverName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/aop/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/mixins/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/services/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/pages/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/servlet/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/tapestry/*.class</exclude>
                            <exclude>com/pvcp/payment/service/web/security/*.class</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                    <check>
                        <haltOnFailure>false</haltOnFailure>
                        <totalBranchRate>25</totalBranchRate>
                        <totalLineRate>25</totalLineRate>
                    </check>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2.Final</version>
                <configuration>
                    <hostname>127.0.0.1</hostname>
                    <username>dark</username>
                    <password>vador</password>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                    only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            org.apache.maven.plugins
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            maven-antrun-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.3,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>run</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>
                                            com.google.code.maven-svn-revision-number-plugin
                                        </groupId>
                                        <artifactId>
                                            svn-revision-number-maven-plugin
                                        </artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>
                                            [1.13,)
                                        </versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>revision</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <ignore></ignore>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.wsdl</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.ldif</include>
                    <include>**/*.tml</include>
                    <include>**/*.js</include>
                </includes>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Can someone help me please. I'll really really appreciate

Comment: Looks more like a dependency issue. Can you post your pom.xml

Comment: @uday thanks. I added the pom.xml.

Comment: The correct filename is `jboss-deployment-structure.xml`. You have a typo in your post. Also you haven't provided the path where you place the aforesaid file.  It should be placed in the top level deployment, in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments).

Comment: @leopal thanks, of-corse the filename was jboss-deployment-structure.xml into the project and added at top level og WEB-INF but didn't work.